# Update using GROUP by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found a couple similar threads but none with just 1 table.  Basically we're doing some updates on our Quote system and there's no great way to find the quote revision history, as the only place it's stored is "priorquoteID."  I wrote a SQL stored procedure that went through and traversed all of the prior quotes and set a new field I created called "OriginalQuoteID" equal to the oldest quote and set the newest quote as "CurrentQuote."

However, about 2/3s of the quotes were never revised so weren't processed by my SQLProcedure. Conceptually I need something that works like this:

```
update 
SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote 
set CurrentQuote = 1
group by OriginalQuoteID
having COUNT(*) < 2
```

So any quotes that don't have a revision (is the only quote in the revision thread) I can mark as current.

Does this make sense? Any ideas?

Comment: The .dbo suggests MS SQL Server, correct?

Comment: not sure I understand what you're asking.. If you've already marked the quotes with prior versions correctly, then doesn;t that mean that the remaining 2/3s of quotes (with no revisions) are current, so should have CurrentQuote=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a sub-query for that:

```
update 
SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote 
set CurrentQuote = 1
where OriginalQuoteID in ( select OriginalQuoteID 
                           from SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote 
                           group by OriginalQuoteID
                           having COUNT(*) < 2
                          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the update below (the inline view  (s) with group by is used for filtering the rows to be updated):

```
update q
    set q.CurrentQuote = 1
from SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote q
join (
    select OriginalQuoteID 
    from SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote
    group by OriginalQuoteID
    having COUNT(*) < 2
) s
on q.OriginalQuoteID = s.OriginalQuoteID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally untested but here is my suggestion.  Make any changes that are necessary to fit with your schema.

```
 WITH quotesToUpdate(QuoteId) AS (
      SELECT Quote.Identifier
      FROM SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote
      GROUP BY OriginalQuoteID HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
 )
 UPDATE SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote
 SET CurrentQuote = 1
 FROM SalesQuotesTest.dbo.Quote q
 INNER JOIN quotesToUpdate qu ON q.Identifier = qu.QuoteId
```